# Do $\{0, 1\}×N$ and $N×\{0, 1\}$ have the same order type?

Tags: order-theory

Do $\{0, 1\}×N$ and $N×\{0, 1\}$ have the same order type? 
Hint: Recall the notion of a successor/predecessor

I am saying they do not and trying to use contradiction.

I have tried to do this by contradiction and assumed that there was a bijective corresponding between them, but I am not too sure on where to go with this, or if there is a different way.

Thank you

Comment: My apologiges I am trying to say they do not*

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833853/order-type-of-mathbb-z-times-1-2-and-1-2-times-mathbb-z?rq=1).

Comment: One of these orders has an element with infinitely many elements that come before it, and the other order does not.